# AJAX Upload multiple files parallel

Tags: ajax, file-upload, xmlhttprequest

There is this function:

```
function uploadFile(f, parent) {

    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

    xhr.upload.addEventListener("progress", function (event) { uploadProgress(event, parent); }, false);
    xhr.upload.addEventListener("load", function (event) { uploadComplete(event, parent); }, false);
    xhr.upload.addEventListener("error", uploadFailed, false);
    xhr.upload.addEventListener("abort", uploadCanceled, false);

    xhr.open("POST", "Upload.aspx", true);
    //xhr.setRequestHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
    xhr.setRequestHeader("X-Requested-With", "XMLHttpRequest");
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data");
    xhr.setRequestHeader("X-File-Name", f.name);
    xhr.setRequestHeader("X-File-Size", f.fileSize);
    xhr.send(f); 
}
```

The parameter "f" of the function is a File that appears on the drop event (event.dataTransfer.files[0])
The problem is that i have multiple elements that fires the drop event (and implicitly the uploadFile function is called) but the upload is not done parallel. First is uploaded the first dropped file and after the upload is complete, only then the second file is uploaded. Why doesn't the files upload parallel?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is done using client side script which is by definition single threaded - one thing at a time, in nature.

Comment: If you'll look at this demo of file uploading, you'll see that the upload appears to be done in parallel: http://aquantum-demo.appspot.com/file-upload Something like this I want to achieve with my script.

Comment: per your link: Requirements
•jQuery v. 1.6+
•jQuery UI v. 1.8+ (required: Widget, optional: Progressbar, Button)
•jQuery Iframe Transport plugin (included)
•jQuery Templates plugin v. 1.0+ (optional)

Comment: Also, your code will not work in IE prior to IE9 as the addEventListener should be attachEvent re: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.addEventListener - see note on that page

Comment: I posted that example to help you makeing an idea about how do I want to look the multiple file uploading...Help me achieving parallel uploading...the rest I can handle it

Comment: SO, it is not acceptable to use the jQuery example you cite?  Perhaps you could examine that code for use if that is the case.